# Use Gradle to access Maven Repo behind Apache Authentication

Tags: apache, maven, authentication, gradle, dependency-management

I'm using gradle scripts with dependency management.
I have a Sonatype Nexus repository sitting on a server that requires me to authenticate via apache before I can view the page.

I think this is stopping me from running my gradle script. My error is `peer not authenticated`.

It is on an SSL server.

Can someone help me with which step I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a certificate and importing it into the Java keystore with `keytool`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step3.html) for how.